can we read and view mirosoft files in flutter app?
hi I am building an all document reader app in flutter but i'm unable to get packages for word ppt files. there is a lot of PDF viewer packages in flutter but there is no package for doc docx ppt etc files.
please let me now how can i achieved this in flutter
i search a lot for the packages and other third party libraries but didn't find any specific package for this functionality

Dependency:
flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer: ^latest_version
syncfusion_flutter_docviewer: ^latest_version
syncfusion_flutter_presentation: ^latest_version

for Pdf:
 body: PDFViewer(document: PDFDocument(file: pdfUrl)),

for word:
  body: SfDocViewer(filePath: docUrl),

for power point:
  body: SfPresentation(filePath: pptUrl),

